# How to implement like button concept in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager which displays images and below that, I added a like button. I can handle the `setOnClickListener` and get the position of the view and increment the like value too.

The problem is, after liking an item and when i reach the last item of the viewPager, the item where i pressed the like, its value is getting back to the old one. When i refresh the fragment, the item is updating to its new like value.

How to handle dynamic refresh of an view in viewPager's adapter?

This is what i have tried.

PageAdapter.java

```
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(final Object object) {
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        final View view;

        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);
        setupItem(view, LIBRARIES[position]);
        Utils.LibraryObject libraryObject = LIBRARIES[position];

        ImageButton b = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.like);

        b.setOnClickListener(v -> addlike(libraryObject, view));
        /* In this function i take the value from the textview, increment it and set its value */

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void addLike(Utils.LibraryObject libraryObject, View view) {

        DatabaseReference usersDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        usersDb.keepSynced(true);
        TextView likeCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.likeCount);
        ImageButton like = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.like);

        // User adds like and increase value in firebase
        usersDb.child(libraryObject.getUserID()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child("likes").exists())
                {
                    int temp;
                    int like = Integer.parseInt(likeCount.getText().toString());
                    temp = like + 1;

                    usersDb.child(libraryObject.getUserID()).child("like").setValue(temp);
                    likeCount.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
                    usersDb.child(libraryObject.getUserID()).removeEventListener(this);
                    like.setClickable(false);
                    like.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I use firebase as backend to store the user details.

Can the adapter be updated from the adapter class itself? Or , how to handle the button onClick of viewPager from the fragment itself?

Comment: add```addlike(libraryObject, view)``` functions code too

Comment: I edited the script @MaratZangiev

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `notifyDataSetChanged` when you update the value.

**Your edited code**

```
@Override
    public int getItemPosition(final Object object) {
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        final View view;

        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);
        setupItem(view, LIBRARIES[position]);
        Utils.LibraryObject libraryObject = LIBRARIES[position];

        ImageButton b = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.like);

        b.setOnClickListener(v -> addlike(libraryObject, view));
        /* In this function i take the value from the textview, increment it and set its value */

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void addLike(Utils.LibraryObject libraryObject, View view) {

        DatabaseReference usersDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        usersDb.keepSynced(true);
        TextView likeCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.likeCount);
        ImageButton like = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.like);

        // User adds like and increase value in firebase
        usersDb.child(libraryObject.getUserID()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child("likes").exists())
                {
                    int temp;
                    int like = Integer.parseInt(likeCount.getText().toString());
                    temp = like + 1;

                    usersDb.child(libraryObject.getUserID()).child("like").setValue(temp);
                    likeCount.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                    usersDb.child(libraryObject.getUserID()).removeEventListener(this);
                    like.setClickable(false);
                    like.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

More in [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Comment: No, Its not working. After clicking the button, there is no change in the textview.